# Formatting Python Output

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to get server information and add it to dictionary for later to be able to create a web page that contains this information.

How would you format this? Would you add it to dictionary or keep it as a list?

```
Command: >>> hpilo.Ilo.get_embedded_health(server_conn):
```

Outout:

> {'fans': {'Fan 2': {'status': 'OK', 'speed': (13, 'Percentage'), 'zone': 'System', 'label': 'Fan 2'}, 'Fan 3': {'status': 'OK', 'speed': (6, 'Percentage'), 'zone': 'System', 'label': 'Fan 3'}, 'Fan 1': {'status': 'OK', 'speed': (6, 'Percentage'), 'zone': 'System', 'label': 'Fan 1'}, 'Fan 6': {'status': 'OK', 'speed': (43, 'Percentage'), 'zone': 'System', 'label': 'Fan 6'}, 'Fan 4': {'status': 'OK', 'speed': (34, 'Percentage'), 'zone': 'System', 'label': 'Fan 4'}, 'Fan 5': {'status': 'OK', 'speed': (43, 'Percentage'), 'zone': 'System', 'label': 'Fan 5'}}, 'health_at_a_glance': {'temperature': {'status': 'OK'}, 'storage': {'status': 'OK'}, 'fans': {'status': 'OK', 'redundancy': 'Redundant'}, 'bios_hardware': {'status': 'OK'}, 'memory': {'status': 'OK'}, 'power_supplies': {'status': 'OK', 'redundancy': 'Redundant'}, 'processor': {'status': 'OK'}, 'network': {'status': 'OK'}}, 'temperature': {'05-P1 DIMM 4-6': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (21, 'Celsius'), 'label': '05-P1 DIMM 4-6', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}, '12-HD Max': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (35, 'Celsius'), 'label': '12-HD Max', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (60, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '10-P2 DIMM 7-9': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (21, 'Celsius'), 'label': '10-P2 DIMM 7-9', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}, '20-VR P1 Mem': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (27, 'Celsius'), 'label': '20-VR P1 Mem', 'critical': (120, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (115, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '32-PCI 5': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '32-PCI 5', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '27-LOM Card': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '27-LOM Card', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '38-PCI 5 Zone': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '38-PCI 5 Zone', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '14-P/S 1': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (21, 'Celsius'), 'label': '14-P/S 1', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '17-VR P1': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (26, 'Celsius'), 'label': '17-VR P1', 'critical': (120, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (115, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '45-SuperCap Max': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (19, 'Celsius'), 'label': '45-SuperCap Max', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (65, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '19-VR P1 Mem': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (31, 'Celsius'), 'label': '19-VR P1 Mem', 'critical': (120, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (115, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '30-PCI 3': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '30-PCI 3', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '07-P1 DIMM 10-12': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (20, 'Celsius'), 'label': '07-P1 DIMM 10-12', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}, '44-System Board': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (23, 'Celsius'), 'label': '44-System Board', 'critical': (85, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (80, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '24-VR P2Vtt Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (26, 'Celsius'), 'label': '24-VR P2Vtt Zone', 'critical': (95, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (90, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '01-Inlet Ambient': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (17, 'Celsius'), 'label': '01-Inlet Ambient', 'critical': (46, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (42, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Ambient'}, '31-PCI 4': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '31-PCI 4', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '03-CPU 2': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (40, 'Celsius'), 'label': '03-CPU 2', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (70, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'CPU'}, '43-BIOS Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (30, 'Celsius'), 'label': '43-BIOS Zone', 'critical': (95, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (90, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System Board'}, '29-PCI 2': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '29-PCI 2', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '34-PCI 1 Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (21, 'Celsius'), 'label': '34-PCI 1 Zone', 'critical': (70, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (65, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '47-Battery Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (25, 'Celsius'), 'label': '47-Battery Zone', 'critical': (80, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (75, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '21-VR P2 Mem': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (30, 'Celsius'), 'label': '21-VR P2 Mem', 'critical': (120, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (115, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '13-Chipset': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (44, 'Celsius'), 'label': '13-Chipset', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (105, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '02-CPU 1': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (40, 'Celsius'), 'label': '02-CPU 1', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (70, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'CPU'}, '42-VR P1 Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (20, 'Celsius'), 'label': '42-VR P1 Zone', 'critical': (100, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (95, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '23-VR P1Vtt Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (24, 'Celsius'), 'label': '23-VR P1Vtt Zone', 'critical': (95, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (90, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '37-PCI 4 Zone': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '37-PCI 4 Zone', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '09-P2 DIMM 4-6': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (28, 'Celsius'), 'label': '09-P2 DIMM 4-6', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}, '22-VR P2 Mem': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (32, 'Celsius'), 'label': '22-VR P2 Mem', 'critical': (120, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (115, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '26-iLO Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (26, 'Celsius'), 'label': '26-iLO Zone', 'critical': (95, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (90, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '50-Sys Exhaust': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (26, 'Celsius'), 'label': '50-Sys Exhaust', 'critical': (80, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (75, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Chassis'}, '41-I/O Board 2': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '41-I/O Board 2', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '48-I/O Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (27, 'Celsius'), 'label': '48-I/O Zone', 'critical': (80, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (75, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '46-Chipset Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (26, 'Celsius'), 'label': '46-Chipset Zone', 'critical': (80, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (75, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '04-P1 DIMM 1-3': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (21, 'Celsius'), 'label': '04-P1 DIMM 1-3', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}, '06-P1 DIMM 7-9': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (20, 'Celsius'), 'label': '06-P1 DIMM 7-9', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}, '39-PCI 6 Zone': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '39-PCI 6 Zone', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '16-P/S 2 Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (24, 'Celsius'), 'label': '16-P/S 2 Zone', 'critical': (80, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (75, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '18-VR P2': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (30, 'Celsius'), 'label': '18-VR P2', 'critical': (120, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (115, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '35-PCI 2 Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (23, 'Celsius'), 'label': '35-PCI 2 Zone', 'critical': (71, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (66, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '08-P2 DIMM 1-3': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (26, 'Celsius'), 'label': '08-P2 DIMM 1-3', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}, '40-I/O Board 1': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (25, 'Celsius'), 'label': '40-I/O Board 1', 'critical': (71, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (66, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '28-PCI 1': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '28-PCI 1', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '49-Sys Exhaust': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (26, 'Celsius'), 'label': '49-Sys Exhaust', 'critical': (80, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (75, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Chassis'}, '25-HD Controller': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (48, 'Celsius'), 'label': '25-HD Controller', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (100, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'System'}, '36-PCI 3 Zone': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (23, 'Celsius'), 'label': '36-PCI 3 Zone', 'critical': (71, 'Celsius'), 'caution': (66, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '33-PCI 6': {'status': 'Not Installed', 'currentreading': 'N/A', 'label': '33-PCI 6', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'I/O Board'}, '15-P/S 2': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (23, 'Celsius'), 'label': '15-P/S 2', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': 'N/A', 'location': 'Power Supply'}, '11-P2 DIMM 10-12': {'status': 'OK', 'currentreading': (21, 'Celsius'), 'label': '11-P2 DIMM 10-12', 'critical': 'N/A', 'caution': (87, 'Celsius'), 'location': 'Memory'}}, 'memory': {'memory_details': {'CPU_2': {'socket 3': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 3, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 2': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 2, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 1': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 1, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 7': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 7, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 6': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 6, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 5': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 5, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 4': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 4, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 9': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 9, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 8': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 8, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 11': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 11, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 10': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 10, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 12': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 12, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}}, 'CPU_1': {'socket 3': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 3, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 2': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 2, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 1': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 1, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 7': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 7, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 6': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 6, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 5': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 5, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 4': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 4, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 9': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 9, 'ranks': 1, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '4096 MB'}, 'socket 8': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 8, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 11': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 11, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 10': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 10, 'ranks': 2, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '16384 MB'}, 'socket 12': {'status': 'Good, In Use', 'socket': 12, 'ranks': 1, 'technology': 'RDIMM', 'frequency': '1333 MHz', 'minimum_voltage': '1.35 v', 'hp_smart_memory': 'Yes', 'type': 'DIMM DDR3', 'size': '4096 MB'}}}, 'advanced_memory_protection': {'configured_amp_mode': 'Advanced ECC', 'available_amp_modes': 'On-line Spare, Advanced ECC', 'amp_mode_status': 'Advanced ECC'}, 'memory_details_summary': {'cpu_2': {'operating_frequency': '1067 MHz', 'operating_voltage': '1.35 v', 'total_memory_size': '192 GB', 'number_of_sockets': 12}, 'cpu_1': {'operating_frequency': '1067 MHz', 'operating_voltage': '1.35 v', 'total_memory_size': '168 GB', 'number_of_sockets': 12}}}, 'firmware_information': {'HP ProLiant System ROM Bootblock': '03/11/2012', 'iLO': '1.13 Nov 08 2012', 'Power Management Controller Firmware Bootloader': '2.7', 'SAS Programmable Logic Device': 'Version 0x0C', 'HP ProLiant System ROM': '12/14/2012', 'Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware': '2.1.5.2B.4', 'HP ProLiant System ROM - Backup': '12/14/2012', 'System Programmable Logic Device': 'Version 0x2D', 'HP Smart Array P420i Controller': '3.42', 'Power Management Controller Firmware': '3.0'}, 'power_supplies': {'Power Supply 2': {'status': 'OK', 'label': 'Power Supply 2'}, 'Power Supply 1': {'status': 'OK', 'label': 'Power Supply 1'}}, 'storage': {'Controller on System Board': {'status': 'OK', 'controller_status': 'OK', 'cache_module_memory': '1048576 KB', 'drive_enclosures': [{'status': 'OK', 'drive_bay': 4, 'label': 'Port 1I Box 2'}, {'status': 'OK', 'drive_bay': 4, 'label': 'Port 2I Box 0'}], 'logical_drives': [{'status': 'OK', 'fault_tolerance': 'RAID 1/RAID 1+0', 'capacity': '136 GB', 'physical_drives': [{'status': 'OK', 'capacity': '136 GB', 'fw_version': 'HPD3', 'label': 'Port 1I Box 2 Bay 1', 'location': 'Port 1I Box 2 Bay 1', 'serial_number': '6XM2R28Z0000B348CPGE', 'model': 'EH0146FBQDC'}, {'status': 'OK', 'capacity': '136 GB', 'fw_version': 'HPD3', 'label': 'Port 1I Box 2 Bay 2', 'location': 'Port 1I Box 2 Bay 2', 'serial_number': '6XM2QLK90000B348DF7V', 'model': 'EH0146FBQDC'}], 'label': '01'}], 'fw_version': '3.42', 'label': 'Controller on System Board', 'cache_module_status': 'OK', 'cache_module_serial_num': 'PBKUC0BRH4A62N', 'serial_number': '5001438025BB71A0', 'model': 'HP Smart Array P420i Controller'}}, 'nic_information': {'iLO Dedicated Network Port': {'network_port': 'iLO Dedicated Network Port', 'status': 'OK', 'port_description': 'iLO Dedicated Network Port', 'ip_address': '10.1.7.84', 'mac_address': '28:92:4a:34:ef:70'}, 'Port 4': {'network_port': 'Port 4', 'status': 'Other', 'port_description': 'N/A', 'ip_address': 'N/A', 'mac_address': 'ac:16:2d:84:56:bb'}, 'Port 3': {'network_port': 'Port 3', 'status': 'Other', 'port_description': 'N/A', 'ip_address': 'N/A', 'mac_address': 'ac:16:2d:84:56:ba'}, 'Port 2': {'network_port': 'Port 2', 'status': 'Other', 'port_description': 'N/A', 'ip_address': 'N/A', 'mac_address': 'ac:16:2d:84:56:b9'}, 'Port 1': {'network_port': 'Port 1', 'status': 'Other', 'port_description': 'N/A', 'ip_address': 'N/A', 'mac_address': 'ac:16:2d:84:56:b8'}}, 'vrm': None, 'processors': {'Proc 2': {'status': 'OK', 'internal_l1_cache': '192 KB', 'name': ' Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz       ', 'memory_technology': '64-bit Capable', 'internal_l2_cache': '1536 KB', 'label': 'Proc 2', 'internal_l3_cache': '15360 KB', 'speed': '2000 MHz', 'execution_technology': '6/6 cores; 12 threads'}, 'Proc 1': {'status': 'OK', 'internal_l1_cache': '192 KB', 'name': ' Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz       ', 'memory_technology': '64-bit Capable', 'internal_l2_cache': '1536 KB', 'label': 'Proc 1', 'internal_l3_cache': '15360 KB', 'speed': '2000 MHz', 'execution_technology': '6/6 cores; 12 threads'}}}

Answer (score 2):

[pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module can help you.

[8.18. pprint — Data pretty printer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)

> The pprint module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter. If the formatted structures include objects which are not fundamental Python types, the representation may not be loadable. This may be the case if objects such as files, sockets, classes, or instances are included, as well as many other built-in objects which are not representable as Python constants.
>
> The formatted representation keeps objects on a single line if it can, and breaks them onto multiple lines if they don’t fit within the allowed width. Construct PrettyPrinter objects explicitly if you need to adjust the width constraint.